# Group By with Union causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to merge output of two queries -

```
select top(10) hex_code from dbo.colors
```

Output -

```
+----------+
| hex_code |
+----------+
| #2ecc71  |
| #3498db  |
| #9b59b6  |
| #f1c40f  |
| #e67e22  |
| #e74c3c  |
| #2980b9  |
| #2c3e50  |
| #27ae60  |
| #f39c12  |
+----------+
```

Query -

```
SELECT top(10) [Product], count([Product]) as Count
  FROM [dbo].[TableA] group by [Product] order by count([Product]) desc
```

Output -

```
+---------+-------+
| Product | Count |
+---------+-------+
| A       |   105 |
| B       |    99 |
| C       |    87 |
| D       |    75 |
| E       |    56 |
| F       |    52 |
| G       |    37 |
| I       |    18 |
| K       |    16 |
| L       |    15 |
+---------+-------+
```

I tried using `UNION` to merge the output but the group by clause is not letting me. I am not sure how to use it with GROUP BY and ORDER BY clause.

I tried -

```
SELECT top(10) [Product], count([Product]) as Count
  FROM [dbo].[TableA] group by [Product] order by count([Product]) desc
UNION
    select top(10) hex_code from dbo.colors
```

But this results in error. Any other way to merge these two columns ?

EDIT - Expected Output

```
+---------+-------+----------+
| Product | Count | Hex Code |
+---------+-------+----------+
| A       |   105 | #2ecc71  |
| B       |    99 | #3498db  |
| C       |    87 | #9b59b6  |
+---------+-------+----------+
for all 10 rows.
```

With ScaisEdge's answer, the out is coming like

```
A    105    #27ae60
A    105    #2980b9
```

Note - Both columns fetch top 10 records. Both tables are not related. (No joins, I suppose)

Comment: When you do an union you need the same quantity of columns in every query. Your first returns 2 columns and the second one returns only 1. (Union in SQL just means stacking up results)

Comment: When bot tables are not related ,what is the logic for showing hex code(#2ecc71) for product A

Comment: The output is further passed on to a JS library which expects third column as color value.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a FULL JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `join` the two tables/queries. If you don't have a column to join on, and you just want the to match each product to an arbitrary colour, you could join on `row_number()`, something like:

```
select p.Product, p.Count, c.hex_code
from (
    SELECT top(10) 
        [Product], count([Product]) as Count,
        row_number() over (order by count([Product])) [rn]
    FROM [dbo].[TableA] 
    group by [Product] 
) p
left join (
    select top(10) 
        hex_code, 
        row_number() over (order by hex_code) [rn]
    from dbo.colors
) on p.rn=c.rn
order by p.Count desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If arbitrary,you can do this..

```
    ;With cte
    as
    (
    SELECT top(10) [Product], count([Product]) as Count
      FROM [dbo].[TableA] group by [Product] order by count desc
    )
  ,cte1
   as(
       select top 10 hex_code from dbo.colors 
     )
    select * from cte c
    cross apply
    (select top 1 hex_code from cte1 order by newid()
    )b
```

Comment: Your query assigns just one color. If change `top 1` to `top 10`, I get same output as ScaisEdge

Comment: Thats what  we get i suppose arbitrarly in limited set of values,you can do a rownumber on bot queries and join them both